# How to count the effective execution time of a thread in a thread pool, not the lifetime of the thread?

Tags: java, time, threadpool

I have encountered a thread timeout problem, I think it may be a thread scheduling problem, but I am not sure if it is like this.
The business scenario is as follows.

My colleague is responsible for writing the service. He uses java's multithreading technology, and the thread pool uses Executors.newFixedThreadPool. The service needs to handle some complex business logic. Complex business logic needs me to support it. I wrote an algorithm module packaged as a jar, and the time for pressure measurement of the algorithm module averaged about 10ms. Of course this is the result in a single-threaded environment. When he puts my module into the program and runs it, when using the pressure test program to test the service, the thread counts the algorithm for more than a few minutes. Of course, this time is the lifetime of the thread. When a single machine uses a program called with the same parameters, the time is still a few milliseconds. So the problem arises. Why is it timed out?

My colleague did not provide me with more details of the program. He thought that the program was time-consuming. I was very angry about his behavior, but the problem always needed to be solved. I don't know much about the thread scheduling algorithm, he is also. Now I want to count the effective execution time of the thread, but I did not see the relevant method in the java.lang.Thread object, I don't know if there are other ways to count it.

I also want to know if there is any other way to explain this problem.

Comment: Add a call to `System.nanoTime()` at the beginning and the end of the `run` method. Calculate the difference and there you got the actual execution time (approximately).

Comment: Calling System.nanoTime will not be helpful if the function is not atomic. For example, the function can start at time t0, executes for 100ms, then the thread is switched out for 1 second. Then when it is resumed, the second nanoTime call will report 100ms + 1 second which is not really what we need

Comment: This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.   The meaning of the API is that it is not a valid CPU execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a **profiler**. A profiler allows you to instrument your code at runtime without having to modify your source code (or packaged jar) to add performance measuring logic. The profiler will tell you the time each thread is executing as well as the time each specific method has been called/executed.

There are many java profilers out there, both gui and cmd. Try **visualvm**, **jProfiler**, or **Java Mission Control** to name a few

Comment: Time profiler tells me whether it is valid time or survival time